# Cannot start Rails from existing rails code and mysql dump

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed an existing app from Github and got the relevant mysql dump and configured database.yml accordingly. But failing to up the server and the following is the result. What am I missing ?
Apologies for the long post
    RAILS_ENV=staging rails server
    exists

```
exists app/controllers
exists app/helpers
exists app/models
exists app/views/layouts
exists config/environments
exists config/initializers
exists config/locales
exists db
exists doc
exists lib
exists lib/tasks
exists log
exists public/images
exists public/javascripts
exists public/stylesheets
exists script/performance
exists test/fixtures
exists test/functional
exists test/integration
exists test/performance
exists test/unit
exists vendor
exists vendor/plugins
exists tmp/sessions
exists tmp/sockets
exists tmp/cache
exists tmp/pids
identical Rakefile
identical README
identical app/controllers/application_controller.rb
identical app/helpers/application_helper.rb
identical config/database.yml
identical config/routes.rb
identical config/locales/en.yml
identical db/seeds.rb
identical config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
identical config/initializers/inflections.rb
identical config/initializers/mime_types.rb
identical config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb
overwrite config/initializers/session_store.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] Y
force config/initializers/session_store.rb
identical config/environment.rb
identical config/boot.rb
identical config/environments/production.rb
identical config/environments/development.rb
identical config/environments/test.rb
identical script/about
identical script/console
identical script/dbconsole
identical script/destroy
identical script/generate
identical script/runner
identical script/server
identical script/plugin
identical script/performance/benchmarker
identical script/performance/profiler
identical test/test_helper.rb
identical test/performance/browsing_test.rb
identical public/404.html
identical public/422.html
identical public/500.html
identical public/index.html
identical public/favicon.ico
identical public/robots.txt
identical public/images/rails.png
identical public/javascripts/prototype.js
identical public/javascripts/effects.js
identical public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
identical public/javascripts/controls.js
identical public/javascripts/application.js
identical doc/README_FOR_APP
identical log/server.log
identical log/production.log
identical log/development.log
identical log/test.log
```

Comment: Can you link to the "existing app from Github?"  What error are you getting?

Comment: That looks like the output from building a **new** Rails project.  If you'd got an existing one of github, you shouldn't be trying to build a new one on top of it.  That's what all the "exists" and "identical" stuff is about.

Comment: Are you perhaps using the command to make a new rails app rather than the command to start the server?

Comment: You did what? To "install" an existing rails app you would use `$ git clone` and not `rails new ...`

Comment: I did a Git clone. The issue is now resolved. Capistrano was used and the server was started using "script/server". It was my noobish error